# How to prevent file uploaded when error happens or user don't fill any required data value with multer node js

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, multer

I wonder how to stop uploading file or creating a folder when error happens with multer.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Here is my code of multer.diskStorage configuration.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let uploadError = new Error('Invalid image type');

    if (!fs.existsSync(userPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(userPath, { recursive: true });
    }

    if (isValid) {
      uploadError = null;
    }
    cb(uploadError, userPath);
  },

  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];

    cb(null, `${uniqueId}-${Date.now()}-${imageName}.${extension}`);
  },
});

const maxSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
const uploadOptions = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
}); code here
```

Comment: Check first if the user has filled everything you need, and procceed then with creating folders etc, otherwise cancel the upload. You are creating a error object and then destroy it. Do it the other way around. Check first everything, if good = go, if not `cb(new Error("Fill all fields please!"))`

Comment: Thanks Marc, I solved this issue already.